# How to check for PostGIS Function Support Matrix for new custom EPSG imported from EPSG site

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, epsg, geography-data-type, projection-mathematics

I need a support for CRS that was not available in PostGIS 2.5 so I looked up into the EPSG site they had simple easy straight forward insert query to add EPSG so I did that now how do I check or know that all the functions that PostGIS have will run with same accuracy as they use to work or may be I should avoid use of some specific function like [given here](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html) , and all reprojection will work as required?

EPSG site reference https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4979/

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 94979, 'epsg', 4979, '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ', 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.017453292519943295],AXIS["Geodetic latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Geodetic longitude",EAST],AXIS["Ellipsoidal height",UP],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4979"]]');
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include the projection string you used.

Answer (score 1):

EPSG:4979 is the same as EPSG:4326, only with a third axis for the height.

PostGIS does not care that the CRS defines a third axis (the PROJ.4 text does not even mention it); it is always possible to use Z coordinates, regardless of how the CRS is defined.

So all reprojections will work, with the same accuracy as the normal EPSG:4326 (WGS84 lat/lon).

To check if a function can work with Z coordinates, see the "2.5D" column in the [PostGIS Function Support Matrix](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix).